# Selecting and deselecting collection of buttons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I have three buttons named `One, Two,` and `Three,` and a function `buttonPressed` for collection of those three buttons as follows.

```
var btnTag = [Int]()

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    guard let button = sender as UIButton? else { return }
    if(btnTag.contains((sender as AnyObject).tag!))
    {
        if let index = btnTag.index(of: (sender as AnyObject).tag!)
        {
            btnTag.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
    else
    {
       btnTag.append((sender as AnyObject).tag!)
    }

    if !button.isSelected {
        button.isSelected = true
        button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
    }
    else
    {
        button.isSelected = false
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

I like to change color of button as `red` when clicked and then when I click other button the previous button color as `white`. So if I press `One,` I want `One` to be `red` and then when I pres `Two`, I want `Two` to be `red` and `One` as `white`. I did the above but it is allowing `multiple selection` and not able to `deselect` previous changes. How do I solve this?

Comment: you need to unselect all buttons before select any other

Comment: So, in that case, I have to create separate outlets for each button. Is there a way, I can do it without creating separate outlets fro each button?

Comment: you can see my answer or there is something called `IBOutletCollection ` that will make you code look much cleaner, by having only 1 outlet for all buttons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply create collection of `UIButton`. After that assign tag of all three `UIButton` from Storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
```

Use above collection and connect all the button with Outlet. also connect below action with all buttons.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    buttons.forEach { $0.isSelected = false
        $0.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    }

    buttons[sender.tag].setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
    buttons[sender.tag].isSelected = true
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Nice explanation :)

Comment: Does `buttons[sender.tag]` work? I was under the impression that outlet collections were in no specific order.

Comment: [This question and top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15189922/1630618) discuss the issue.  Apparently outlet collections do have an order, but it is a bad practice to depend on that order because there is no way to verify it.

Comment: Finally, wouldn't `sender.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)` and `sender.isSelected = false` be sufficient.  It doesn't matter where the `sender` is in the outlet collection.

Comment: @vacawama, if we give tag numbers to buttons, doesn't it work?

Comment: My problem is with the statement `buttons[sender.tag].isSelected = true`.  It is a bad practice to depend on the order of items in an `@IBOutlet` collection.  I don't see why that is necessary anyway. `sender.isSelected = true` should be sufficient here.

Comment: @vacawama, got it, you are correct. Thanks for poinitng that out.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are highlighting only one button at the moment, you don't need tag array instead the reference to all buttons.

```
//Let say these are my button refrence
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
```

All of those buttons are targeting same method

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

     //clear all button selected state
     clearSelectedState()

     //select the button that was clicked
     sender.isSelected = true
     sender.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
}


func clearSelectedState() {

     button1.isSelected = false
     button1.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)

     .... proceed to do for others
}
```

Now in `clearSelectedState` method I don't like the repetition of code. So what we can do is put the reference in array and do something like

```
///this can be replaced in clear state method
[button1, button2, button3,...].forEach {
       $0.isSelected = false
       $0.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
}
```