# Multiple Choice Quiz: Need to set title of each button to each question multiple choice answer

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a multiple choice quiz. All of the data is being parsed through json. I have 5 questions and each question has 5 multiple choice answers. Currently I set the question number, title of the question with description, and have the 5 buttons with each question.

It is working with one exception. Each of the buttons is displaying the same question instead of each individual question. I assume that I need to create a loop that loops through the question and appends it to each button, but am having trouble figuring this out.

Here is an example of what I see:

[image: multiple choice quiz screen shot]

Here is the code I have written:

```
@IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var questionCounter: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var questionNumber: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var questionTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var questionText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var optionA: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var optionB: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var optionC: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var optionD: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var optionE: UIButton!

//Below is for parsed json data version
var allQuestions = [Questions]()
var questionNumbers: Int = 0
var AnswerQuestions: Int = 0
var selectedAnswer: Int = 0

func updateUI() {

    self.questionNumber.text = String(surveyQuestions?.questions[questionNumbers].questionNumber ?? 0)

    self.questionTitle.text = surveyQuestions?.questions[questionNumbers].category.name

    self.questionText.text = surveyQuestions?.questions[questionNumbers].text

    self.questionText.text = surveyQuestions?.questions[questionNumbers].text.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)


    optionA.setTitle(surveyQuestions?.questions[questionNumbers].answerChoices[AnswerQuestions].text, for: UIControl.State.normal)
    optionB.setTitle(surveyQuestions?.questions[questionNumbers].answerChoices[AnswerQuestions].text, for: UIControl.State.normal)
    optionC.setTitle(surveyQuestions?.questions[questionNumbers].answerChoices[AnswerQuestions].text, for: UIControl.State.normal)
    optionD.setTitle(surveyQuestions?.questions[questionNumbers].answerChoices[AnswerQuestions].text, for: UIControl.State.normal)
    optionE.setTitle(surveyQuestions?.questions[questionNumbers].answerChoices[AnswerQuestions].text, for: UIControl.State.normal)

    print("Success")

}
```

From what I have gathered there are a few ways to possibly do this.

```
for button in question {
button.setTitle(question?.questions[number].text, for: UIControl.State.normal)
}
```

or

```
for i in 0...<button.count {
button.setTitle(question?.questions[number].text, for: UIControl.State.normal)
}
```

If anyone can help me out that would be awesome.

Thanks and if you need more details or info I can provide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set first index of `answerChoices` array for all options with `AnswerQuestions` initially  = 0 , instead you need

```
optionA.setTitle(surveyQuestions?.questions[questionNumbers].answerChoices[0].text, for: .normal)
optionB.setTitle(surveyQuestions?.questions[questionNumbers].answerChoices[1].text, for: .normal)
optionC.setTitle(surveyQuestions?.questions[questionNumbers].answerChoices[2].text, for: .normal)
optionD.setTitle(surveyQuestions?.questions[questionNumbers].answerChoices[3].text, for: .normal)
optionE.setTitle(surveyQuestions?.questions[questionNumbers].answerChoices[4].text, for: .normal)
```

It'll be easier if you have created an IBOutlet collection

```
@IBOutlet var allOptions: [UIButton]!
```

and hooked all buttons to it , in this case you can do

```
allOptions.indices.forEach { allOptions[$0].setTitle(surveyQuestions?.questions[questionNumbers].answerChoices[$0].text, for:.normal)  }
```

Comment: It’s not a good idea to depend on the order of the items in an outlet collection. Perhaps you should use the tag. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15189922/1630618

Comment: @Sh_Khan thanks I cant believe it was something as simple as this. Thanks for helping out. And yes I am using the tag method.

Comment: @Sh_Khan I am running into another problem. When I parse the data into my question text label I am obviously getting the text to come through, but there are also image links within the text. Ex: "https://website.com/imagepath/imagename.png". How do I parse the url string and apply it to a UIImage?