# How can I add make an array for all of my IBOutlets?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

*These are my Outlets, how can I out all off these in an array?*

```
@IBOutlet weak var progressBar1: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var progressBar2: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var progressBar3: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var progressBar4: UIProgressView!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the Assistant Editor, right-click and drag from one of your UIProgressView's or just drag from its "Referencing Outlet Collections" to the code file.
[Insert outlet collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xADwG.png)

Then you can drag from your swift file's @IBOutlet to the rest of your UIProgressView's. [Add view to collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ8Z3.png)

Comment: Where would I put the array, when I place it somewhere in the code it gives me this Error. "Cannot use instance member 'progressBar1' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" It does this for all of the progress views.

Comment: @kaleb outlet collection is a simple array, so you can access items using indexPath:  `let progressBar1 = collection[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

On top declare a variable first like this

```
var outlets: [UIProgressView] = []
```

and now on **ViewDidLoad** method you can use this to put all outlets on that array

like this:

```
outlets = [progressBar1, progressBar2, progressBar3, progressBar4]
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: Where would I put the array, when I place it somewhere in the code it gives me this Error. "Cannot use instance member 'progressBar1' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" It does this for all of the progress views.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var p1: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var p2: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var p3: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var p4: UIProgressView!
    
    var outlets: [UIProgressView] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        outlets = [
            p1,p2,p3,p4
        ]
    }
}
```

If you have other types of views you can use

```
var outlets: [UIView] = [...]
```

Comment: Where would I put the array, when I place it somewhere in the code it gives me this Error. "Cannot use instance member 'progressBar1' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" It does this for all of the progress views.

Comment: Both Faysal and Bobby answers cover it - but I updated my example with code that compiles with no error just in case (:

Comment: ok, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here [Swift - IBOutletCollection equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052459/swift-iboutletcollection-equivalent) you can use **IBOutletCollection** to do that. You can drag all your views to one IBOutlet array.

```
@IBOutlet weak var progressBars: [UIProgressView]!
```

For example, you can access the first progressBar like

```
progressBars[0]
```

But you have to careful about the order of progressBars, when you define **IBOutletCollections the collection will not be order guaranteed**. You can define the for each view and sort by their tags in runtime as mentioned here also [Is IBOutletCollection guaranteed to be of correct order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189922/is-iboutletcollection-guaranteed-to-be-of-correct-order)

To order all views by their tags like

```
progressBars = progressBars.sorted { $0.tag < $1.tag }
```